# mongo statefulset FailedMount volume after scale up replica

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am testing mongodb statefulset to have 3 replicas after using it for a while. It has some pods that restart and show error FailedMount.

this my file mongo-statefulset.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb-stg
  namespace: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
        selector: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      serviceAccount: mongo-account
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: docker.io/mongo:4.2
        env:
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "mongod --replSet=rs0 --bind_ip_all"]
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 128Mi
        ports:
        - name: mongo-port
          containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-data
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

I am checked PV and PVC is found that all 3 disks still exist.

check "kubectl get volumeattachment" is not have mount node with PV of pods at fail.
(node status is Ready all)

This logs on the nodes failing to start that pod.

```
{MESSAGE: E0825 18:33:45.862680 1629 kubelet.go:1761] "Unable to attach or mount volumes for pod; skipping pod" err="unmounted volumes=[mongo-data], unattached volumes=[mongo-data kube-api-access-mjvpr]: timed out waiting for the condition" pod="mongo/mongo-stg-0", PRIORITY: 6, SYSLOG_FACILITY: 3…

{MESSAGE: E0825 18:33:45.862835 1629 pod_workers.go:951] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="unmounted volumes=[mongo-data], unattached volumes=[mongo-data kube-api-access-mjvpr]: timed out waiting for the condition" pod="mongo/mongo-stg-0" podUID=de8858da-251c-48c3-be7e-c6bda3286350, PRIORITY: 6,…
```

Tried delete pvc and scale down/up replica mongo pods is comeback Running but using it for a while is fail again.

Why not create volumeattachment on node at pods run.

Comment: "Why not create volumeattachment on node at pods run" => check CSI controllers, and kubelet logs on the nodes failing to start that pod. share those logs. Avoid using screenshots: better write down those logs as plain text, here.

Comment: This logs on the nodes failing to start that pod {MESSAGE: E0825 08:41:44.620760 1625 pod_workers.go:951] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="unmounted volumes=[mongo-data], unattached volumes=[mongo-data kube-api-access-fj6zl]: timed out waiting for the condition" pod="mongo/mongodb-stg-2" podUID=97ca91bb-6822-4dd7-af74-1ebda5472dcf, PRIORITY: …